# Appropriate way to deal with file-names and file-name components ("paths") in emacs lisp?

Tags: files

What is a good, clean  to deal with paths in emacs lisp?
Common lisp has pathnames, Python has os.path. But I always seem to end up reinventing the wheel and resorting to manual regexes for simple path operations like getting a path basename, dirname, or joining paths together in a sane way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [f.el](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) package is a collection of prefixed functions wrapping existing functions as referenced in [File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html) and comes with a few of its own.  I've found it useful to study its code for figuring out which built-in functions to use, but you can use it like a regular library as well.

Comment: thanks, this looks like it is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

What you are, I think, calling "paths" Emacs and Emacs Lisp call "*absolute*" file or directory names. In Emacs language, a *"path"* is a list of absolute directory names, as used, for example, in the environment variable `PATH` and Emacs variables `exec-path` etc. (And yes, Common Lisp refers to these as "paths".)

Wrt the question of getting parts of a file name, combining them, etc., see the Elisp manual, node [File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html) and its subnodes, such as [File Name Components](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html).

Beyond that, your question is very general (and risks being closed as too broad). Please consider posing a specific question -- something that you want to do with file names or file-name components. Your question is OK as asking for general info about Emacs file-name functions, but a specific how-to question would also be useful.

Comment: I've used these before but I've found them lacking and not robust, eg I think the recommended way of joining components is just concatenating them together, and assuming directories always end in a slash, etc, which is too low level for my taste. 
I think my question is specific enough, for example, what is the emacs lisp analogue of Python's os.path library or CL's pathname which offer comprehensive tools for dealing with paths.

Comment: This is obviously not the best way but I can't find your email anywhere, I've been using your help-fns+.el and there's a bug when a keymap is not bound to a symbol. Where can I report this (to you)?

Comment: I understand that there is no variable documentation without a variable, all I'm saying is that you can easily omit it in the case that a keymap object is passed instead of a variable. my workaround it's as simple as `(setq some-random-sym kmap) (describe-keymap 'some-random-sym)`, really using an advice and gensym. My case is that I'm creating anonymous, autogenerated keymaps (via (let ((kmap (make-sparse-keymap)) ...) from commands in a file and I'm binding one of its keys to a description of itself. Just thought I'd make a suggestion but no problem if you're not inclined towards it

Comment: Yes, that's useful for non-interactive use -- good suggestion. I've done something similar now -- [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el)

Answer (score -2):

elisp has the list `load-path`. When you want to add a new path to the scope, just do

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "my/new/path")
```

Then, supose you have a file.el in that directory. In the end of the file, put the line `(provide 'file)`, and then you can require it with:

```
(require 'file)
```

You can also require files in subfolders of your load-path, if they are provided as such, with

```
(require 'subfolder/file)
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. i'm trying to deal with paths in general, not just for the purpose of loading emacs lisp code.